# Integrate ruby variable into a js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How I can integrate ruby variable into a js file. I would like to render a partial relative to the current step of registration of my User. 
But I can't succeed it, Rails do not translate @flat.current_step in his value (which is a integer). Any ideas ?

```
$('.flats').replaceWith("<%= j render partial: 'flats/steps/step#{@flat.current_step}' %>");
```

Error

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Missing partial flats/steps/_step#{@flat.current_step}
```

Comment: What do you mean "can't succeed"?

Comment: Well the code is not working, I have a error of template

Comment: "I have a error of template" - how are we to know what's wrong? Post the error, in its entirety.

Comment: Rails do not translate @flat.current_step in his value (which is a integer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ruby does not interpolate the `#{}` when wrapped in single quotes. Change your call to:

```
$('.flats').replaceWith('<%= j render partial: "flats/steps/step#{@flat.current_step}" %>');
```

Comment: @stigGaret: nope, you had something different. This should work (given that `@flat.current_step` does indeed result in an integer).

Comment: No se, I've tried to replace the line by an alert("<%= @flat.current_step%>") and is well working !! (The result should be 3)

Comment: ActionView::Template::Error (Missing partial flats/steps/_step#{@flat.current_step}